# Can I add a Lightning Component to Page Layout?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

If yes - how can I do this?

Header:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
```

Comment: You cannot put a component in between fields in a page layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lightning App Builder and Page layouts are different concepts.

Lightning App Builder:

- You can add lightning components by dragging standard and custom components to your record, app or home pages.

Page Layouts:

- Here you can customize on what is visible on record detail page like Fields, Related Lists, Pages, etc. In lightning UI, the page layout is visible on Record Detail Component.

---

Short answer to your question:

> Can I add a Lightning Component to Page Layout?

- Not unless you expose the lightning component to visualforce page using lightning out, recommended and more user friendly way is to add components to app builder.

Answer (score 2):

For your requirement, you cannot directly place the lightning component in between the fields in page layout.

One workaround is , refer your lightning component in a visualforce page and add the vf page in the page layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the lightning component using app builder into record page,home page
setting --> app builder --> select the page you want drag the lighting component from left panel to right side

Comment: I know it, thank you. But I need it on my Page Layout (this component should be between a few fields). And I have no idea how to make it a part of page layout.

Comment: Do you mean component inside component...like one component having two fields inbetween new component

Comment: I mean a simple record's Page Layout where: field, field, field, section with Lightning Component, field, field, another Lightning Component, field, field.